# Is Sebastian Sallow a pure-blood wizard?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

Do we know Sebastian Sallow's blood status in the game?

Is he pure-blood, half-blood, or Muggle-born?

[image: Sebastian Sallow - Hogwarts Legacy]

Comment: What exact purpose does this question really serve, when there already exists a 3rd party wiki that answers these questions? Generally making your own questions with self answers only helps when a 3rd party resource doesn't yet exist for the question

Comment: @childe There are 3rd party wikis for many games, Minecraft is one of them. But that doesn't stop people from still asking Minecraft questions here that are already answered on the wiki. Not everyone wants to look through a wiki for an answer and this is where a site like this shines because of the quick Q&A. If someone now searched "Is Sebastian Sallow a pure-blood wizard?" or something similar, then they'll instantly find this and see the answer instead of having to spend a lot of time searching through wikis for it.

Comment: Most Minecraft questions are extremely technical and specific questions, or the question was asked at a time when the information regarding it was not as well known.  There's a reason why we don't have questions like "How to craft a torch" or "How to make a pickaxe"

Comment: "or something similar, then they'll instantly find this and see the answer instead of having to spend a lot of time searching through wikis for it." -- I've learned that it's not wise to use your questions for SEO purposes.  I did this many years back and learned it's not the right way to use this site.

Comment: It's unfortunate that your question got downvoted. Lore questions are fine and on-topic on Arqade, but this kind of question might fit better and get more positive attention at [scifi.se] SE.

Comment: Lore questions are fair game, but questions like the "how to craft a torch" fall under low research effort as described here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down. This one would fall in that category given the info's provided in the first google result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian is definitely not Muggle-born. Both his parents were wizards, meaning he was not Muggle-born.

We don't know whether his parents were pure-blood or not though.

So Sebastian is either **pure-blood** or **half-blood**.